How to Handle Context API Selection Without Affecting Other Cards
I've been working on a project where I need to render a list of medicines from an API. Here is a brief overview of my steps:

Created a Search Bar: The search bar fetches the output using the provided API.

Render Cards Based on API Data: The API returns a length based on the search value, which I use with the map method to create cards.

Available Forms Rendering: The API contains different available forms such as:


   {
       "available_forms": [
           ["Tablets"],
           ["capsule", "oral"],
           ["Tablets", "injection"],
           ["capsule"]
       ]
   }

Based on the available_forms length, I used the map method to render each form in a card using <li> tags.
Example:
Card 1: Tablets
Card 2: Capsule Oral
Card 3: Tablets Injection

Click Behavior Issue:
I added an onClick method to the <li> tag. When clicking Card 1 Tablet, it also selects Card 3 Tablet when using Context API. Note: I don't want this behavior. If I click Card 1 Tablet, only that should be selected, not other Tablets.
Desired Behavior:
When using useState in the local file, only the clicked card element is selected, which is the correct behavior.
Here is the sample API response for reference:
   {
       "data": {
           "saltSuggestions": [
               {
                   "id": 487,
                   "salt": "Paracetamol+Paracetamol",
                   "salt_frequency": 19,
                   "available_forms": [
                       "Tablet"
                   ],
                   "most_common": {
                       "Form": "Tablet",
                       "Strength": "300mg+700mg",
                       "Packing": "10 tablet sr"
                   },
                   "salt_forms_json": {
                       "Tablet": {
                           "300mg+700mg": {
                               "10 tablet sr": {
                                   "2863": [
                                       {
                                           "pharmacy_id": 3,
                                           "selling_price": 50
                                       },
                                       {
                                           "pharmacy_id": 2,
                                           "selling_price": 44
                                       }
                                   ],
                                   "31440": null,
                                   "75341": null
                               }
                           }
                       }
                   }
               }
           ]
       }
   }

My Code (Summary)
Here is the relevant part of my code that demonstrates the issue:
   import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';
   
   // Assuming MedicineContext is set up properly
   import { MedicineContext } from './MedicineContext';
   
   const MedicineList = () => {
       const { medicines } = useContext(MedicineContext);
       const [selectedForm, setSelectedForm] = useState(null);
   
       const handleClick = (form) => {
           setSelectedForm(form);
       };
   
       return (
           <div>
               {medicines.map((medicine, index) => (
                   <div key={index}>
                       <h3>{medicine.salt}</h3>
                       <ul>
                           {medicine.available_forms.map((form, idx) => (
                               <li key={idx} onClick={() => handleClick(form)}>
                                   {form.join(' ')}
                               </li>
                           ))}
                       </ul>
                   </div>
               ))}
           </div>
       );
   };
   
   export default MedicineList;

The Issue
When using Context API, clicking on Card 1 Tablet also selects Card 3 Tablet. I only want the clicked item to be selected. When I switch to using useState in a local file, the selection works as expected.
Desired Solution
I need help to achieve the behavior where clicking on an item only selects that specific item without affecting others when using Context API.
